# Rename tons of files

Tags: terminal, regex, rename, mv

How can I rename all the files with a pattern like this:

```
thumb_f318d8a580ca5717d686a323b6c2ca0d.jpg0000777
thumb_f18d8aup90ca5717d686a323b6c2c5uh.jpg0000777
thumb_jessr8d8a580ca5717d68623etrtckks.jpg0000777
thumb_4hghd8a580ca5717d686a323b6c2ghjj.jpg0000777
....
```

to

```
thumb_f318d8a580ca5717d686a323b6c2ca0d.jpg
thumb_f18d8aup90ca5717d686a323b6c2c5uh.jpg
thumb_jer8d8a580ca5717d686a323etrtckks.jpg
thumb_4hghd8a580ca5717d686a323b6c2ghjj.jpg
....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use bash variables and a for loop:
`for i in *;do mv $i ${i%0000777};done`

when you surround the variable name with {} and add a % sign, it returns the value of the variable with everything after the % removed.

If you use a # sign it will remove from the beginning of the string. so
`for i in *;do mv $i ${i#thumb_};done`
Would strip the thumb_ off the front.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [rename](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rename.ul) script. Assuming that they all end with "0000777":

```
rename -nv 's,0000777$,,' *
```

If the output is what you want remove the `-n` parameter to make it actually rename them.

Comment: I believe that redhat-type distributions (fedora, etc) have a different rename program that works differently (doesn't support regexes), and you'll have to install `rename.pl` separately.

Comment: rename on Debian/Ubuntu systems actually comes as part of perl.  It is also know as prename.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention an OS but by the use of your tags I'm going to assume *nix.

However, if you're on Windows regular CMD prompt:

```
ren *.jpg0000777 *.jpg
```

or powershell:

```cs
Get-ChildItem *.jpg0000777 | Rename-Item -NewName {  $_.Name -replace ".jpg0000777",".jpg"  }
```